# FileUpload unknownError

Tags: genexus, fileupload

Estoy intentando subir un archivo pdf desde cliente al servidor, pero el control me da el error "unknownError".
El archivo se abre bien desde Acrobat.
Estoy trabajando con Genexus 16, generador Java, contra un Wildfly 8.0

Adjunto imagen
[image: Error al subir pdf]

Answer (score 0):

De pronto es bueno debugear en el browser (F12) a ver qué error específico aparece.

No sé qué upgrade de V16 estás usando pero hay un error reportado y corregido en V17 que puede ser la causa de tu problema: https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=48239;;

También fue corregido en V16U11 Hot Fix: http://dcserver.genexus.com/gxsync/gxbuild16.0.11.169120_v16u11hf.zip

Answer (score 0):

gracias por la respuesta.

El problema era que el Wildfly tiene en su configuración un tope de tamaño máximo definido para la suba de archivos.
Por defecto sólo se pueden subir archivos de hasta 10mb. Se subió ese valor y se solucionó el problema!

Muchas gracias!